# how to send id with form in php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a Dynamic page (holidays.php), which comes data from id using get method like this in url holidays.php?id=1

the code is

```
include('header.php');
include('db.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql_hp = "select * from `holiday_package` where `id` ='$id'";
$res_hp = mysql_query($sql_hp);
$rec_hp = mysql_fetch_array($res_hp);
```

and I have a contact form in same page which client fills and send an email to admin.

```
<form action="holidays-form.php" method="post">
          <!--<span class="success"><?php echo $smsg; ?></span>
          <span class="fail"><?php echo $emsg; ?></span>-->

          <h3>Book Package</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-elements">
             <label>Name</label>
             <div class="form-item">
                <input type="text" name="name" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-elements">
             <label>Email ID</label>
             <div class="form-item">
                <input type="email" name="email" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-elements">
             <label>Contact Number</label>
             <div class="form-item">
                <input type="text" name="mobile" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>

          <div class="form-select-date">
            <div class="form-elements">
              <label>Select Travel Date</label>
              <div class="form-item"><i class="awe-icon awe-icon-calendar"></i>
                <input type="text" name="date" class="awe-calendar" value="Date" required="required">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-select-date hide">
            <div class="form-elements">
              <label>Select Package</label>
              <div class="form-item">
                <input type="hidden" name="pkg_title" value="<?php echo $rec_hp['pkg_title'];?>">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-elements hide">
             <label>Package Price</label>
             <div class="form-item">
                <input type="hidden" name="pkg_price" value="<?php echo $rec_hp['pkg_price'];?>" />
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>


          <div class="form-group" style="margin-top:-15px;">
            <div class="form-elements">
              <label>No. of Guest</label>
              <div class="form-item">
                <select name="adult" required>
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                  <option value="6">6</option>
                </select>
              </div>
             </div> 
             </div>

          <div class="price"><em>Total Cost for this Package</em> <div class="amount" id="cost_dv">INR <?php echo $rec_hp['pkg_price'];?>/-</div></div>
          <div class="form-submit">
            <div class="add-to-cart">
              <button type="submit">Send Query for Booking</button>
            </div>
          </div>



          </form>
```

I am sending mail through holidays-form.php page, see the code below

```
<?php

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
  $date = $_POST['date'];
  $pkg_title = $_POST['pkg_title'];
  $pkg_price = $_POST['pkg_price'];
  $adult = $_POST['adult'];
  $from = 'Company Name';

  $to = "info@companyname.com";
  $subject = "New Holiday Package Submission";

  $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
  $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";



  $message = '<html><body>

 <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:#ccc solid 1px;">

      <tr>
               <td width="151" height="30" style="background:#f3f3f3;     padding-left:5px;">Name</td>
               <td width="149" style="background:#f3f3f3; padding-   right:5px;">'.$name.'</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
          <td height="30" style="padding-left:5px;">Email</td>
          <td style="padding-right:5px;">'.$email.'</td>
        </tr>

       <tr>
            <td height="30" style="background:#f3f3f3; padding-left:5px;">Mobile</td>
            <td style="background:#f3f3f3; padding-right:5px;">'.$mobile.'</td>
          </tr>
       <tr>
             <td height="30" style="padding-left:5px;">Date</td>
             <td style="padding-right:5px;">'.$date.'</td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td height="30" style="background:#f3f3f3; padding-left:5px;">Package Name</td>
            <td style="background:#f3f3f3; padding-right:5px;">'.$pkg_title.'</td>
          </tr>

           <tr>
             <td height="30" style="padding-left:5px;">Package Price (adult)   </td>
             <td style="padding-right:5px;">'.$pkg_price.'</td>
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td height="30" style="background:#f3f3f3; padding-left:5px;">Package Price (child)</td>
            <td style="background:#f3f3f3; padding-right:5px;">'.$adult.'</td>
          </tr>



   </table>
   </body></html>';

$success = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if ($success == true) {

 header("Location:holidays.php?s=mail sent");
 }
  else {
   header("Location:holidays.php?s=error");
 }


?>
```

I want to show success message in holidays.php and I have Written the code in form tag like this

```
<?php

   $s = $_GET['s'];
  if ($s=="mail sent") {
      echo ('<span class="success">Thankyou! Your Package Has been      Successfully Submitted!. We will Feedback you asap.</span>');
  }

  else if ($s=="error") {
    echo ('<span class="fail">Sorry! Please ensure you have filled all fields Correctly.</span>');  
  }
```

but after submitting the form holidays.php page showing an error like ( Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\tricky-traveler\holidays.php on line 4 ) with success message. so how can I store or send the $id value which I used in the top of the page.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated and in the recently released PHP 7.0 deleted use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Give a hidden `<input />` field (if you are using `GET` method):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

If you are using `POST` method, simply change your PHP as:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Or change your `<form>` tag to:

```
<form action="holidays-form.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: Don't use `sir`. What did you try and what else could be an easy method than this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden form field

```
<input type="hidden" name="pkg_price" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_REQUEST['id']);?>" />
```

And make sure that you change the `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST` when checking the `$id`, since you post the form (so it will appear in `$_POST` or `$_GET`).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id?>">

//and in php page get your id using  

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql_hp = "select * from `holiday_package` where `id` ='$id'";
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.